Making Rest Assured Jar executable
My Rest Assured project build is successful and now I want to run the jar file (making it executable).
For that I tried running java -jar application-name.jar
But it is giving me error cannot find or load main class.
How can I fix it?
I tried java -jar application-name.jar

but it is giving error cannot find or load main class


If you're using Maven, try the Shade plugin

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Does this answer your question? How can I create an executable/runnable JAR with dependencies using Maven?

no because there is no main class in rest assured project we need to run whole test suit

Is the code publicly available?

no we are doing jenkin integration and facing error failure
